# phpunit method getNumAssertions returns 0

Tags: php, phpunit

i'm using PHPUNIT 3.4.5, and i would like to get the total number of assertions done by my tests (3 assertions for my sample code).
The method "getNumAssertions" keeps returning 0.

```
    public function test_DateUtil()
{
    echo "\nNumAssertions : " . $this->getNumAssertions() . "\n";
    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    echo "NumAssertions : " . $this->getNumAssertions() . "\n";
}

public function test_DateUtil_2()
{
    echo "\nNumAssertions : " . $this->getNumAssertions() . "\n";
    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    echo "NumAssertions : " . $this->getNumAssertions() . "\n";
}
```

}

PHPUnit returns :

```
phpunit --configuration phpunit_dev.xml --verbose
PHPUnit 3.4.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.
UtilTest
NumAssertions : 0
NumAssertions : 0
.
NumAssertions : 0
NumAssertions : 0
.
Time: 1 second, Memory: 13.50Mb
OK (2 tests, 3 assertions)  ------------> what i want to get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::getCount()](http://apidoc.phpunit.de/classes/PHPUnit_Framework_Assert.html#getCount)

```
public function test_DateUtil()
{
    echo "\nNumAssertions : " . PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::getCount() . "\n";
    $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    echo "NumAssertions : " . PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::getCount() . "\n";
}
```

Your code is not producing the expected output because the method `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::addToAssertionCount` is called outside of the test itself, and it is not called until the completion of the test.

Therefore, you will not be able to get the assertion count from within the test method using `getNumAssertions()`.

You will find the call to

`$test->addToAssertionCount(PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::getCount());`

near the end of the method

`PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult::run`

***EDIT***

The output after running all tests is done by `PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter` which contains the `protected` property `$numAssertions`.  There is no accessor(getter) for this property.

You can [extend the PHPUnit framework](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/extending-phpunit.html) and add this functionality.

One option would be to extend the `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` class, overload the `run` method and increment a custom `total assertions` counter from there.

Another option would be to extend the `PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter` class similar the HTML Result Printer in [this article](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/11/phpunit-create-a-resultprinter-for-output-in-the-browser/).

If you want to send an email of the entire output without extending PHPUnit, you can [pipe the results to an email application](https://serverfault.com/questions/370935/how-to-sendmail-via-command-line-piping).

There is also [jenkins](http://jenkins-php.org/), which can handle this as well as much more.

***NOTE***

I am using 3.3.17

Comment: getCount returns the number of assertions for one test. I would like to be able to get the total number of assertions for all my tests (without having to increment a variable) How to get the number of assertions printed by PHPUnit at the end of the execution

Comment: do you want to get the number of assertions from within a test?

Comment: no, just at the end of my test suite (id like to send it by mail)

Comment: Sounds too old, none of these don't even exist.